# Zebra datepicker select event isn't firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why doesn't my code work on localhost? After the user opens the calendar and selects a date, an alert message is supposed to pop open, but that isn't happening. It is working on jsfiddle.net.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Zebra_DatePicker examples</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14855/zebra/css/default.css" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Zebra_datepicker/1.9.4/javascript/zebra_datepicker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date1" value="Select First Date"/>
        <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date2" value="Select Last Date"/>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".datepicker").Zebra_DatePicker({ format: "d-m-y" }); 
         });
            $("#date1").Zebra_DatePicker({
              onSelect: function() {
                $(this).change();
                alert($(this).context.value);
              }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What sorts of errors do you have in your JavaScript console? And when you're running it local, does that mean `file:///` or `http://localhost/`?

Comment: I dont take any error. I mean http://localhost

Comment: Can you please clarify what "doesn't work" means? Does it mean the date pickers aren't showing up? (That's what I'm assuming)

Comment: Sorry.  I just cant get alert message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I poked around and found what could be a problem.

If I understand things correctly, the second call of `.Zebra_DatePicker()` is being overwritten. The first selection, `$('.datepicker')` is happening *after* the more specific `$('#date1')`. The specialized date picker is initialized during page load. When `$.ready()` happens, the special date picker is getting *overwritten* by the other date picker, thus erasing the `onSelect`.

You could fix it by placing both in the `$.ready` handler, like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Zebra_DatePicker examples</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14855/zebra/css/default.css" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Zebra_datepicker/1.9.4/javascript/zebra_datepicker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date1" value="Select First Date"/>
        <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date2" value="Select Last Date"/>
        <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".datepicker").Zebra_DatePicker({ format: "d-m-y" }); 
            $("#date1").Zebra_DatePicker({
              onSelect: function() {
                $(this).change();
                alert($(this).val());
              }
            });
         });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This worked on my localhost.

On a side note, `$(this).context.value` <strike>doesn't seem to work</strike> is [deprecated in jQuery 3.0](https://api.jquery.com/context/) (which you happen to be using). Use `$(this).val()` instead.

Comment: Thanks you so much. You really saved me.